# TypeError: _firebase_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.auth is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Can someone explain this error to me with the context to my code if possible. Written in React.js for user authentication using firebase:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import firebaseConfig from "./firebase.js";

export const AuthContext = React.createContext("");

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        firebaseConfig.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            setCurrentUser(user);
            setLoading(false);
        });
    }, []);
    if (loading) {
        return <p>Loading...</p>;
    }
    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ currentUser }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

The firebase.js file looks something like this:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "*******************************",
  authDomain: "react-firebase-auth-****.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://react-firebase-auth-****.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "react-firebase-*******",
  storageBucket: "react-firebase********.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "**********",
  appId: "****************************",
});

export default firebaseConfig;
```

Comment: you forgot `import "firebase/auth"`

Comment: Can you share firebase.js?

Comment: @NishargShah Still the same

Comment: @Dharmaraj check it now

Comment: Initialize your firebaseConfig with `const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);` and then use `firebaseApp.auth()`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you’re trying to call it before it’s imported/loaded.
Please, could you modify your firebase.js file and use my code:
Note: I changed the way to import firebase

```
import firebase from "firebase"; //noted this
import "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "*******************************",
  authDomain: "react-firebase-auth-****.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://react-firebase-auth-****.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "react-firebase-*******",
  storageBucket: "react-firebase********.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "**********",
  appId: "****************************",
});

//noted this
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
 
} else {
  firebase.app(); // if already initialized, use that one
}
export { firebase }  //noted this
```

Comment: I get your point that my code is trying to call it before it has loaded. But even on the implementation of your code, it throws the error. It shows this error: `Attempted import error: '../firebase.js' does not contain a default export (imported as 'firebaseConfig').`

Comment: @lagan Please, note that in my code i exported like this: export { firebase }  
so you have to change your import to something like this: import {firebase}

or the last option, it is modify my export and do it like this: export default firebase, and you dont need change nothing in your code.

Please try again and let me know.

Comment: the thing is that whenever i try to import firebaseConfig in some other file, it throws the 'attempted import' error since it as never exported in the firebase.js file. It might be silly at my end but i'm unable to reach the solution. Any help?

Comment: I answer you in my previous comment. Also, your actual issue isnot related with your initial question. 
Could you share your actual code of your firebaseConfig ? I will point the line where you have the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting Firebase services individually like this instead of exporting everything:

```js
  import firebase from 'firebase/app';
  import 'firebase/auth';

  const firebaseConfig = {...};

  if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  }
 
  const auth = firebase.auth();

  export {auth}
```

Importing and usage:

```js
import {auth} from "./firebase"

auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {...})
```

Comment: i've described the error on implementing this code in the above answer